# cannot insert data to by data base table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect('localhost', '   ', '    ') ;
$db=mysql_select_db('    ') ;
$name=$_POST['name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$mobile=$_POST'mobile'];
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO user (name, email, mobile)
VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$mobile')";
if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) 
{
echo "New record created successfully";
} 
else{
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $con->error;
}
$con->close();
?>`
```

i am trying to insert data into my table but it throwing a error 
help me to solve this problem .

my error:

```
syntax error, unexpected ''mobile'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)
```

Comment: what is the error ? ans also show table structure

Comment: updated my error check it out.

Comment: `$mobile=$_POST'mobile'];` here you missing `[`.

Comment: Don't use `mysql_*` its no longer supported use mysqli or pdo also use prepared statements.

Comment: error online 6 `$mobile=$_POST'mobile'];` should be `$mobile=$_POST['mobile'];`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why shouldn't I use mysql\_\* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

This is suppposed to be a comment, but i have a low reputation here.

Before i answer your question, please do not use the mysql functions as its no longer supported . Consider a switch to either MYSQLI or PDO. Also, do not trust user input. Meaning do not directly post field values from your form to your database as an attcker can easily exploit it by adding funny javascripts or worse.
It wont work because, you forgot to open the square brackets,

$mobile = $_POST['mobile'];

To your question, try this:

```
  $sql = "INSERT INTO user (`name`, `email`, `mobile`)VALUES 
 ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['name'])."', 
 '".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['email'])."', 
 '".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['mobile'])."')";
```

where the variable $conn is your database connection